# What does the method linkUserId: do in the Dropbox iPhone API?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I was just wondering what this method does because just from the title it seems like it should prompt the user to log in with a specific username but that is not what it does it doesn't do anything differently as far as I can tell...

```
- (void)linkUserId:(NSString *)userId;
```

Comment: "it doesn't do anything differently" from what?

Comment: it doesn't do anything differently from the link method in the dropbox API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is used to relink your account.
This small part of my code explains how this function works.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark DBSessionDelegate methods
- (void)sessionDidReceiveAuthorizationFailure:(DBSession *)session userId:(NSString *)userId {
    relinkUserId = [userId retain];
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] 
       initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"DropBoxSessionEnd",@"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"ReLinkQuestion",@"") delegate:self 
       cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",@"") otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Relink",@""), nil]
      autorelease]
     show];

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIAlertViewDelegate methods

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if (index != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkUserId:relinkUserId];
    }
    [relinkUserId release];
    relinkUserId = nil;
}
```

This function opens "Link" Dropbox page without prompting about user login.

Comment: actually that call is (now at least): [[DBSession sharedSession]linkUserId:(NSString *)userID fromController:(UIViewController *)controller];